# hook or filter on post show

Tags: php, wordpress, feed, wordpress-hook

What hook/filter should I use for not display some post on my blog, (for example if the post written over the last year.) 
I want to use hook / filter and not code in the template so plugins or rss feed can't access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [`pre_get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, this hook is called after
>   the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is
>   run. So you have use it with different conditional.

Here is the sample code:

```
function wh_getThisYearPost($query)
{
    if (($query->is_home()) //<-- for home page
        || $query->is_feed() //for feed
        || $query->is_search() // for search
    )
    {
        //to get post from current year only.
        $query->set('year', date('Y'));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wh_getThisYearPost');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Please Note: The above code will not work on your custom `WP_Query` you have manually add the [*Date Parameters*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) in those query.

Hope this helps!

Comment: my year is in acf filed. can I still use this?

Comment: @user186585: yes, replace `date('Y')` with your ACF, but the dateformat should be `YYYY` ex. 2017.

Comment: You want this for specific `post_type` archive page only?

Comment: my problem is in the global search result

Comment: ooh so that means you want whenever a user search it should get the post belong to a specific `post_type` and which are published in a specific year right? If so then Yes it is achievable.